# How can I insert a period without affecting equation alignment?

Tags: align, punctuation

Here is the setup that I currently have:

```
\[\triangle A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}\sim\triangle A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}\]
\[\Big\Downarrow\]
\vspace{-1.75em}
\begin{align}
    \angle C_{1}A_{1}B_{1}&=\anglen C_{2}A_{2}B_{2}\\
    \angle A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}&=\angle A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}\\
    \angle B_{1}C_{1}A_{1}&=\angle B_{2}C_{2}A_{2}.
\end{align}
```

However, the period at the end of the equations causes the environment to be offset. I tried putting the whole thing in an align envrionment but the verticle arrow does not seem to align properly to the center.

**Edit:** I figured it out, putting `\rlap{.}` at the end works, thank you!

Comment: Try `\rlap{\quad.}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put them all in one `align` environment, and if you really want to center the down arrow you can use `\shortintertext`, for instance. An arguably better option is to define a variant of `\vdotswithin` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\Whaterverwithin[2]{%
\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#1{}}}][c]{{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\triangle A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}&\sim\triangle A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}\notag\\
\shortintertext{\hfill$\displaystyle\big\Downarrow$\hfill\mbox{}}
    \angle C_{1}A_{1}B_{1}&=\angle C_{2}A_{2}B_{2}\\
    \angle A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}&=\angle A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}\\
    \angle B_{1}C_{1}A_{1}&=\angle B_{2}C_{2}A_{2}.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\triangle A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}&\sim\triangle A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}\notag\\
& \Whaterverwithin{=}{\displaystyle\big\Downarrow}
\notag\\
    \angle C_{1}A_{1}B_{1}&=\angle C_{2}A_{2}B_{2}\\
    \angle A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}&=\angle A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}\\
    \angle B_{1}C_{1}A_{1}&=\angle B_{2}C_{2}A_{2}\;.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]